# sudo missing on Palm WebOS - can I add it?

Tags: sudo, webos

I've rooted my Palm Pre (WebOS 1.4.5) and installed a SSH server on it. Now I'd like to SSH into it with an unprivileged user and use sudo for elevated commands.

However: There is no sudo on the system. Can I add it somehow?

Comment: why not just use `su -c 'command'`?

Comment: @xenoterracide: Because I have literally no idea about 
Linux. ;-) This is is a busybox based system, BTW. `su` tells me `"su: must be suid to work properly"`.

Comment: @tolomak, yeah it would have to be suid... do you have root access? can you `chmod` it?

Comment: @xenoterracide, sure I can. I did a `chmod 4755 /bin/su` and `su` works now, thanks. :) I also found a way to install sudo itself, took me a while to get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the way to do it (was rather easy after all):

- prerequisite: [Preware](http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Preware) is installed (done this already)
- install `ipkg-opt` (called the "Optware Advanced Linux Command Line Installer" in Preware)
- connect to your device command line as `root` (via novaterm/USB cable or SSH, if already installed)
- call `ipkg-opt update`
- call `ipkg-opt list | grep sudo` to make sure the package is available
- call `ipkg-opt install sudo`

At which point my device did:

```
palm-webos-device ipkg # ipkg-opt install sudo
Installing sudo (1.7.4.4-1) to root...
Downloading http://ipkg.nslu2-linux.org/feeds/optware/cs08q1armel/cross/unstable/sudo_1.7.4.4-1_arm.ipk
Configuring sudo
Successfully terminated.
```

I assume an unpriviledged user has already been added to the system. Now modify `/opt/etc/sudoers`:

- `chmod 640 /opt/etc/sudoers` (make writable for root)
- add permission for that user to the file (`username ALL=(ALL) ALL`)
- `chmod 440 /opt/etc/sudoers` (make readlony again)

Now SSHing into the device as the unprivileged user and using `sudo` from there should work.