# Why would I keep home directories in /var/home?

Tags: linux, fhs, webos

As far as I understand, the traditional place for home directories is beneath `/home`. Some Linux variants seem to keep them in `/var/home`, what's the reason for that?

Comment: might I ask what variants? I've never seen that. It's definitely against FHS

Comment: @xenoterracide: You might have guessed from [my other question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3836/sudo-missing-on-palm-webos-can-i-add-it), this is about WebOS again. `/home` just contains symlinks to `/var/home`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that WebOS is designed to be installed on two different filesystems, a root filesystem that is read-only in normal operation and a filesystem mounted on `/var` that is read-write in normal operation. Since home directories need to be writable, they are placed somewhere under `/var`. This kind of setup is fairly common on unix systems that run off flash (such as PDAs¹ and embedded unices).

While `/home` is mentioned by the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) on Linux and is generally common amongst unices, it is not universal (the FHS lists it as “optional” and specifies that “no program should rely on this location”). Sites with a large number of users sometimes use `/home/GROUP/USER` or `/home/SERVER/USER` or `/home/SERVER/GROUP/USER`. And I've seen directories rooted in other places: `/homes`, `/export/home`, `/users`, `/net`, ... In fact, a long long time ago, the standard location for home directories was `/usr`.

¹ <sub>For example Android (not a unix, but running on a Linux kernel) has a read-only root filesystem and a writable filesystem on `/data`.</sub>

Comment: and dont forget the original /usr for home directories

Comment: @camh: I'm too young to have seen it, but yes, I might as well mention it.

Comment: Yes, that's a decent explanation. The root file system on WebOS is indeed mounted as read-only in normal operation and must be remounted before one can modify system files.

Answer (score 3):

I never seen that...

But you can place things more or less all over the place, I mean one user can be in /var/home/ another in /home/ and third in /partyplace/home/....

But it just don't make any sense to me, it's better to follow the convention that users data is stored under /home/

Comment: There are [indications](http://www.google.de/search?q=move+home+%22var/home%22) that this is not entirely unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

/var might be on a different partition or disk.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that as well. In this case, it isn't - it's a smartphone and it all runs off a single flash memory module.

Comment: But home can also be on another partition as well... so this makes no sense.

Comment: @Johan: you might want to group things together; not just have home on another partition.